# Export pandas dataframes to different rows in Excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas, export-to-excel

I am able to write dataframes to sheets but I want to write it to different rows in a single sheet using python pandas dataframes.

```
df8 = pd.DataFrame(item1(doc))
df9 = pd.DataFrame(item2(doc))
df10 = pd.DataFrame(item3(doc))
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('m1.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df8.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='item1')
df9.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='item2')
df11.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='item3')
writer.save()
```

Efforts so far.

```
df12 = pd.DataFrame(group_dataframes,index=['item1', 'item2', 'item3']).T
df12.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='consolidated_sheet')
```

how to group_dataframes?

Comment: Use `df.concat` and only save `to_excel` once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing `keys` with `concat`

```
df12 = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3],keys=['item1', 'item2', 'item3'])
```

Comment: df12 = pd.concat([df8,df9,df10],axis=1, keys=['item1', 'item2', 'item3'])